# How does Bigtable handle Tablet Server failures?

Tags: bigtable, nosql

I have found that Bigtable cluster consists of a single master server and multiple tablet servers. Message sent to tablet server by master during failure. Backup copy of tablet made primary. Extra replica of tablet created automatically by GFS.

[image: Architectural diagram including Chubby, Bigtable, GFS, etc.]

Is it enough? But I want to know how to solve it actually or What's the procedure or Which steps actually followed to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

There is a single distributed file system that Bigtable uses, not several different ones, and all the tablet servers access the same file system.

In this file system, the tablets (SSTables) are already stored durably replicated, so when a single tablet server fails, a new one is assigned by the master to handle the data handled by the original tablet server, but no data copying is necessary, because the new tablet server can access the same data as the old one, on the same distributed file system.